# Is it dangerous to share toothpaste?

Tags: infection, hygiene, toothpaste

Can a person get some dangerous disease (Hepatitis, HIV, etc) from another person by sharing a toothpaste with them?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. Your question as it stands is very broad. There are a lot of dangerous diseases. Some may be able to be transmitted in certain circumstances, and some may not. Are you asking if Hepatitis can be transmitted by sharing toothpaste, are you asking if HIV can, or are you asking about another? You can ask multiple questions, so please can you narrow your criteria to stipulate one disease you are concerned about in one question and also let us know what you read about the possibility?